# PhpMyAdmin displays SUBTIME() output as hexadecimal dump

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I execute the example from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime I don't get the answer in the format shown there. This is the example:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999','1 1:1:1.000002');
        -> '2007-12-30 22:58:58.999997'
```

But the answer I get is:

```
323030372d31322d33302032323a35383a35382e393939393937
```

If you remove every second letter from that answer you get

```
2007d12d30022a58a58e999997
```

...which is almost the expected string. Maybe the conversion from some internal format to the actual representation goes somehow wrong?

I used PhpMyAdmin to execute the SELECT on my provider's web server. With PhpMyAdmin on my local machine it works correctly, i.e. as shown in the MySQL docs.

**EDIT:** The answer I get is actually the string representation of the hexadecimal character values of the DATETIME string, see http://www.asciitable.com/. But I still don't know how that happens.

Comment: When you execute a SELECT in PhpMyAdmin it displays a web page containing a table with each row of the result set. So in this case a table with one row and one column. The value displayed in that column was the answer I got instead of the expected DATETIME string.

Comment: You should try your query directly in MySQL, not phpmyadmin. In SQLyog for example, I get this: 2007-12-30 22:58:58.999997

What you have seems to be encoding / decoding issue.

Comment: When I run `SELECT SUBTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999','1 1:1:1.000002')` on PHPMyAdmin, I get back `2007-12-30 22:58:58.999997`. It's probably either the version you are using or some config setting for your instance of PhpMyAdmin (presumably  something having to do with web-safe characters or the like)

Comment: Yeah, if you convert all known invalid entries to be the equivalent "percent encoded" value, example : `2d` changes to `%2d`, and assume that the `3`s occurring map to `%03`, you get: `%032%030%030%037%2d%031%032%2d%033%030%20%032%032%3a%035%038%3a%035%038%2e%039%039%039%039%039%037` which is the URL-encoding for the correct value.

Comment: Also have a look at : https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you're talking about is this one: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/6321 which will be fixed in version 4.6.0. I've just tested with the pre-release version of 4.6.0 and it looks correct, so I suggest upgrading once 4.6.0 comes available.

Comment: thanks! that seems to be the problem. Casting to text then shows the wanted string: `SELECT CAST(SUBTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999','1 1:1:1.000002') AS CHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8)`